# Sort a list of Objects by date attribute

Tags: java

i have a list that contains Objects with a Calendar field which stores the date.
i would like to sort my list by dates how could this be done?
I have tried using the List.sort but could not figure out how to compare Calendar objects.

Comment: "Java sort attribute" seems the perfect keywords to find out a solution ;)

Comment: Here is a post with some answers: [sort-arraylist-of-calendars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44563175/sort-arraylist-of-calendars).